# TDD With MVC Repository pattern

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, tdd, nunit

I am in the process to design architecture for mvc based project. For better approach i want to use TDD (using NUnit framework) pattern. I have fallowing layers in project.

1. MVC Project
2. Application Service layer.
3. Domain Service layer
4. Infrastructure layer

Function calls will be executed same way as numbering for layers.
I want to use TDD concept from 'Application Service layer' (Not from controllers of MVC).
First of all tell me is it right way to use TDD from layers other than MVC.& secondly I am confused that if I am going with this way, how i will make call to application layer functions for crud operations as application layer functions have internal calls to domain service layer functions for crud operations.I tried by giving direct call to application layer functions by creating its class object but it is giving error that object reference not set to instance of object.

My code is

```
using ApplicationServices.AppServiceInterfaces;
using ApplicationServices.AppServiceClasses;
using PeocitEntities.MasterEntities;

 namespace MyUnitTest
{
[TestFixture]
public class Account_Group
{
    AccountGroupApplnService accApplicationServiceObject;

    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void SetupTest()
    {
        accApplicationServiceObject = new AccountGroupApplnService();//Here iam getting error
    }

    [Test]
    public void AddAccountGroup()
    {

        AccountGroup accountGroupObj = new AccountGroup();

        accountGroupObj.strName = "Test TDD Group";
        accountGroupObj.intGroupType = 10;
        accountGroupObj.groupType_name = Enum.GetName(typeof(EnumTypelib.glAccountGroupTypes), accountGroupObj.intGroupType);
        accountGroupObj.intPrimaryGroup = (int)EnumTypelib.PrimaryGroupType.as_liabilities;
        bool IsGroupAccountCreated = accApplicationServiceObject.CreateAccountGroup(accountGroupObj);//Internally calls service & then infra layer.
        Assert.True(IsGroupAccountCreated);
    }


    [TestFixtureTearDown]
    public void TearDownTest()
    {
        accApplicationServiceObject = null;
    }
}
```

}

My question is how to use TDD(with Nunit) for application having multiple layers?

Answer (score 2):

An approach you should consider here is **Outside-In TDD**. I'll outline an overview in very broad brushstrokes, but I'd strongly recommend studying [Growing Object-Oriented Software Driven by Tests](http://www.growing-object-oriented-software.com/) and/or [Outside-In Test-Driven Development](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/outside-in-tdd) for further detail.

### Walking Skeleton & Spiking

It's incorrect to say that TDD precludes anything but unit tests. With Outside-In, our first tests should exercise the external boundaries of our application with the minimal viable functionality to do so.

We can then write an end-to-end test for the thinnest possible slice of functionality across all boundaries, exercising the system from the outside to the inner most layer. At this point, if you're going to be touching an external dependency like a database, for example, you'll want to use NUnit's `[SetUp]` and `[TearDown]` attributes to initialise and delete fake data for each test.

Completing these steps can take longer than we might expect as there may be a significant amount of infrastructure that needs setting up. However, doing so ensures we have a feasible architecture to build from.

### Acceptance & Unit Testing

At this point we won't have a great deal to show for our efforts and we'll want to start filling in the details with some useful behaviour. Before implementing a single feature, broad acceptance tests for that feature can be written and we can then zoom in on the unit level and utilise the [red-green-refactor](http://www.jamesshore.com/Blog/Red-Green-Refactor.html) cycle in a smaller scope -- the unit -- to build the different layers of our application.

This is when we'd use a [mocking framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37359/what-c-sharp-mocking-framework-to-use) to isolate each unit from the rest. If we maintain something akin to an [onion architecture](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/), consistently applying TDD, we'll end up with a well-tested, loosely-coupled system.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your point, you are not describing *unit* tests, you are describing *integration*tests, which should not be the outcome of TDD. You should not test multiple layers at once. A better approach is to test your layers in isolation, so you should try to mock / stub your dependencies. You can use a mocking-framework to setup your expected behaviour of the dependencies.

Comment: Maybe a good start would be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37359/what-c-sharp-mocking-framework-to-use

Comment: Thanks once again. :)